# Feature scaling for Kmeans algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I know feature scaling is required for KMeans algorithm defined under
sklearn.cluster.KMeans

My question is whether it needs to be done manually before using KMeans or KMeans does automatically perform feature scaling? If automatic, please show me where is it specified in KMeans algorithm as I am unable to find it in the documentation present here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Btw people say that Kmeans itself takes care of Feature Scaling.

Answer (score 6):

If your variables are of incomparable units (e.g. height in cm and weight in kg) then you should standardize variables, of course. Even if variables are of the same units but show quite different variances it is still a good idea to standardize before K-means. You see, K-means clustering is "isotropic" in all directions of space and therefore tends to produce more or less round (rather than elongated) clusters. In this situation leaving variances unequal is equivalent to putting more weight on variables with smaller variance, so clusters will tend to be separated along variables with greater variance.[image]

A different thing also worth to remind is that K-means clustering results are potentially sensitive to the order of objects in the data set1. A justified practice would be to run the analysis several times, randomizing objects order; then average the cluster centres of those runs and input the centres as initial ones for one final run of the analysis.

or other multivariate analysis.

1 Specifically, (1) some methods of centres initialization are sensitive to case order; (2) even when the initialization method isn't sensitive, results might depend sometimes on the order the initial centres are introduced to the program by (in particular, when there are tied, equal distances within data); (3) so-called running means version of k-means algorithm is naturaly sensitive to case order (in this version - which is not often used apart from maybe online clustering - recalculation of centroids take place after each individual case is re-asssigned to another cluster).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but probably you didnt understand my question. I aksed,"Does Kmeans perform feature scaling by itself"?

Comment: I would say no. The way kmeans algorithm works is as follows: <br>
Specify number of clusters K.
Initialize centroids by first shuffling the dataset and then randomly selecting K data points for the centroids without replacement.
Keep iterating until there is no change to the centroids.i.e assignment of data points to clusters isn’t changing.
Compute the sum of the squared distance between data points and all centroids.
Assign each data point to the closest cluster (centroid).
Compute the centroids for the clusters by taking the average of the all data points that belong to each cluster.

Comment: Since there is no reference, I wanted to give a credit to a person who wrote exactly the same post here in 2012 (@ttnphns): https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21226/56357
@Anshul Singh, my apologies if you are the same person who wrote the original post as you do not seem to be

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, K-means does not automatically perform feature scaling. Anyway its a simple process and requires just two additional lines of code. I would recommend using [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler) feature scaling. Here is a good [example](https://chrisalbon.com/machine_learning/clustering/k-means_clustering/) on how to do it.

```
from sklearn import datasets    
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

iris = datasets.load_iris()    
X = iris.data    
scaler = StandardScaler()
X_std = scaler.fit_transform(X)
clt = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=0, n_jobs=-1)
model = clt.fit(X_std)
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to perform feature scaling manually but my question is whether it is done inside kmeans or not because people endorse this fact but I am not able to find it inside its documentation!